# distance from root search of tree fails

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

The tree is as follows:

```py
       (1,1)
       /   \
    (2,1)  (1,2)
    / \      / \
 (3,1)(2,3) (3,2)(1,3) 
      and onward
```

The root is (1,1), all values in the tree are tuples.

```
Where (x,y) is an element of the tree:
The leftChild will be (x+y,y)
The rightChild will be (x,x+y)
```

I am building a function that finds the distance from the root (1,1). I cannot build the tree from scratch as it will be too time consuming.

I have found that 1 distance from the tuple being searched for we must subtract the the max with the min. We can work backward.

```
     1      2
(3,2)->(1,2)->(1,1)
(3,2)->(3-2,2) = (1,2)->(1,2-1) = (1,1)
given this is always true:
if x > y:
   newtuple = (x-y,y)
   distance += 1
else if y > x:
   newtuple = (x,y-x)
   distance += 1
```

Yet because possible test cases can go up to even x = 10^50, this is even too slow.

So I have found a formally to find the amount of subtractions of x with y or vice versa to make a x > y change to y < x and vice versa until (x,y) = (1,1).

So X - Y(a certain amount of times, say z) will make x less than y...
X - Y*z = y
find z via algebra... z = (Y-X)/(-Y)

This is my code so far:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import math

def answer(M,F):
    M = int(M)
    F = int(F)
    i = 0
    while True:
        if M == 1 and F == 1:
            return str(i)
        if M > F:
            x = math.ceil((F-M)/(-F))
            M -= F*x
        elif F > M:
            x = math.ceil((M-F)/(-M))
            F -= M*x
        else:
            if F == M and F != 1:
                return "impossible"
        i += x
        if M < 1 or F < 1:
            return "impossible"

    return str(i)
```

And it's not passing some unknown test cases, yet passes all the test cases I can think of. What test cases could I be failing? Where is my code wrong?

p.s. used Decimal module, just removed from code to make more readible.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original question?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 http://pastebin.com/tJ2p3YN7

Comment: Is it from an online judge where I can test my implementation?

Comment: Not a public one sadly.. I can test the implementation myself though.

Comment: How did you implement the first solution?

Comment: @A. Sarid I simply subtracted the max with the min of the tuple until it was (1,1) and if it ended up being <= 0, it was set to impossible.

Comment: Have you tested if it is an overflow issue? I am not sure if the Decimal package can handle number up to 10^50 without losses.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Floor division allows for no loss, but maybe -1 in error which I consider for the code below.

```py
def answer(M,F):
    M = int(M)
    F = int(F)
    i = 0
    while True:
        if M == 1 and F == 1:
            return str(i)
        if M > F:
            x = F-M
            x = x//(-F)
            if F < M-(F*x):
                x += 1
            M -= F*x
        elif F > M:
            x = M-F
            x = x//(-M)
            if M < F-(M*x):
                x += 1
            F -= M*x
        else:
            if F == M and F != 1:
                return "impossible"
        i += x
        if M < 1 or F < 1:
            return "impossible"

    return str(i)
```